# Why does my code return NAN and Infinity?

Tags: javascript, nan, infinity

I'm trying to make a simple BMI calculator. However, if I just hit the calculate button, after the alert it renders the NAN as a 'result'. And if I just input the weight, it returns an Infinity response. I made several changes to the code structure but nothing solved this bug.

```js
const heightInput = document.querySelector(".height-input");
const weightInput = document.querySelector(".weight-input");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const statement = document.querySelector(".statement");

document.querySelector(".calculate").addEventListener("click", calculateButton);


function calculateButton() {

  let height = heightInput.value;
  let weight = weightInput.value;
  let BMI = weight / (height ** 2);
  result.innerText = BMI.toFixed(1);

  if (BMI < 18.5) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está abaixo do peso ideal. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if ((BMI > 18.5) && (BMI < 24.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Seu IMC está dentro da normalidade.";
  } else if ((BMI > 25) && (BMI < 29.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com sobrepeso. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if ((BMI > 30) && (BMI < 34.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com obesidade grau I. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if ((BMI > 35) && (BMI < 39.9)) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com obesidade grau II. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else if (BMI > 40) {
    statement.innerText = "Você está com obesidade grau III. Consulte um médico para fechar um melhor diagnóstico.";
  } else {
    window.alert("Por favor, adicione as informações abaixo");
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>IMC</title>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Calculadora de Índice de Massa Corporal (IMC)</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="calculator-container">
    <h1>Calcule o seu IMC</h1>
    <form action="#">
      <p>Insira sua altura em metros:</p>
      <label for="height">Altura:</label>
      <input class="height-input" id="height" name="height" type="number" placeholder="Ex: 1,70" required>
      <p>Insira o seu peso em kilogramas:</p>
      <label for="weight">Peso:</label>
      <input class="weight-input" id="weight" name="weight" type="number" placeholder="Ex: 70" required>
    </form>
    <button class="calculate">Calcular</button>
    <h3 class="result"></h3>
    <p class="statement"></p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `Infinity` is because the calculation does a division by `0`. And NaN may be caused by an operation with undefined or null (or any non-numeric string) as an operand. You should provide default values for those cases. Or maybe deactivate the calculate button as long as both valid values are not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check if both `height` and `weight` have a value.

Because when you press calculate button with no input it can't be done the operation to get `BMI`, and the result is `NaN` (Not a number).

Also, when you input a `weight`, but no `height`, the operation fall in a division by zero, and that's why the result is Infinity.

So, the best way to avoid that kind of problems is to check if both `height` and `weight` have a value. If some of them is missing, just don't do nothing.

```
function calculateButton() {

  let height = heightInput.value;
  let weight = weightInput.value;

  if (height == '' || weight == '') {
      return; //Nothing to do
  }

  let BMI = weight / (height ** 2);
  result.innerText = BMI.toFixed(1);

  if (BMI < 18.5) {
    //Here your code (I don't repeat it)
  }
};
```

But that's quite simple and you must go more ahead. You must check if values are valid numbers. You can use `parseFloat()` function, and then check with `isNaN()`:

```
function calculateButton() {

  let height = parseFloat(heightInput.value);
  let weight = parseFloat(weightInput.value);

  if (isNaN(height) || isNaN(weight)) {
      return; //Nothing to do
  }

  let BMI = weight / (height ** 2);
  result.innerText = BMI.toFixed(1);

  if (BMI < 18.5) {
    //Here your code (I don't repeat it)
  }
};
```

Finally, you can show an error message when a value is given but is not a number. I let you this on your own.